# Fire a Javascript function after submitting a Gravity Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a multi-page form where the url remains the same when moving between pages.

I am trying to change some HTML after the submit button has been clicked.

I can run this in the console and the result is as I want it.

How can I get this run after submit?

I've tried `window.onload` and `document.onload` functions but they are not working. I've also tried an onclick function but it seems moving to the next page stops this working?

```
var confirm = document.getElementById('gform_confirmation_message_14');
if(confirm) {
   document.getElementsByClassName("entry-title")[0].innerHTML = "PAYE Worker";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [`gform_page_loaded` event](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_page_loaded/)? From the documentation it:

> Fires on multi-page forms when changing pages (i.e. going to the next or previous page).

```
$(document).on('gform_page_loaded', function(event, form_id, current_page) {
    // do stuff
});
```

There are [a bunch of javascript events](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/category/javascript/) available, and if not this one, maybe another serves your purpose, e.g. [`gform_post_render`](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_post_render/).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Javascript completely and created a confirmation in Gravity Forms that redirects to a new page upon submission.

Created a title for this new page "PAYE worker"

Problem solved